# How to auto-refresh Servlet with POST method making data persist

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet configured with POST method to get submitted data from the web, but at the same time a Weblistener process runs in background updating some global variables I have defined in my the servlet class. I get the values for this variables from a remote sensor every 5 second.
I would like that servlet automatically auto-refresh showing the new values, similar to the manually result when pressing button submit (even without any value to be submitted) getting visible the new values.

Any idea for a solution?

Note:
Using  or including  code like response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5) doesn't work because the values don't persist and the page shows all the variables as NULL.

Comment: web-socket or ajax polling is the answer

Comment: Websocket was a good idea. Now it works fine. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Save data in session and if getParameter() returns null when reloading ,retrieve data from the session using getAttribute() method.